# How does Vieta work with cubics, quartics, and equations with degree greater than $2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Alright, so with a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c$, I know the sum of the two roots would be $-b/a$ and the product of the two roots would be $c/a$. However, how does Vieta work with equations that have degree greater than $2$: $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, for example. Would the formulas hold the same: $-b/a$ for sum, $c/a$ for product, or would there be variations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Comment: Here there are some methods for a cubic equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html, his page has excellent information on the vieta formulas, and why they work, and even give an example for second and third order polynomials. Essentially you can related the coefficients to symmetric polynomials in the roots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there are Vieta formulas for every degree. We can prove them now, very quickly.

Firstly, note that there's no reason for $a$ to not be $1$, as we just divide everything else by it. So let's look at the cubic
$$ x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d.$$
We know this has three roots. Let's call them $r_1, r_2, r_3$. Then we also know that the cubic can be written as
$$ (x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3) = x^3 - (r_1 + r_2 + r_3)x^2 + (r_1r_2 + r_1r_3 + r_2r_3)x - r_1r_2r_3.$$
Comparing these two gives Vieta's formulas, including for instance that the product of the roots corresponds to the constant term.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. But will I have to derive a new vieta formula every time I encounter an equation with a different degree?

Comment: @awdreg you might notice that it's the $n$th symmetric polynomial in $n$ roots for the constant coefficient, the $(n-1)$st symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables for the degree $1$ coefficient, and so on. Up to sign.